# Search two lists for at least one match with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way (on average) to compare two lists with LINQ (query syntax or otherwise)

```
var A = new [] { 1, 2, 3, ... };
var B = new [] { 4, 1, 5, ... };

bool match = 
    // Some LINQ expression
```

such that `match` will be true when at least one element in the first list (1 in this case) equals an element from the second? I don't need to know how many matches there were, or even which one was matched, just that there was at least one match.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure there is.

```
A.Intersect(B).Any();
```

`Intersect` is always useful in the least expected circumstances.

Comment: @EricB They are all correct, in the sense that they will give you the same answer. This one is the most efficient for large sets.

Comment: @EricB Right, this performs about the same (99% of the time better) with small sets, and better still with large sets.

Comment: I was curious so I tested it out. It turns out that when `A` is significantly larger than `B` (i.e. 10K-1M in `A`, compared to 10 in `B`), `A.Intersect(B).Any()` is significantly (70%-90%) faster than `B.Intersect(A).Any()`. This is because `Intersect` first build up the internal set by iterating completely through the second parameter, and then iterating through the first parameter only as needed.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `Intersect`, but that would calculate all matches, which you don't need.  So `Any` is better, since it will short-circuit:

```
bool match = A.Any(a => B.Any(b => b == a));
```

Comment: Good point. I never thought `Intersect` fully operates before yielding. It makes sense.

Comment: @SimonBelanger Right, but worst case this is `O(mn)`. Sure, best case is `O(m)`, but best cases are not common. `Intersect`, otoh, is always `O(m+n)`.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance It really comes down to the specific cases then. Thank's for the info, always curious to see the complexity of different LINQ operators.

Comment: OP: the fact that `Any` is better depends on the circumstances, so stop spreading facts that may (and probably are) not be true.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I don't so. `Intersect` uses a internal set to determine whether the items in `B` are also in `A`. To do this it has to repeatedly check all items in the set as it's building up the intersection. It *might* be faster but it's still `O(mn)` I think.

Comment: @p.s.w.g OK... I'm kind of lying. It's `O(n+m)` best case (no hash code collisions) but only `O(nm)` if all of them have hashcode collisions (e.g. the `GetHashCode` implementation is just something like `return 13;`)

Comment: Even `Intersect` uses deferred execution.  It does *not* need to generate the entire intersection to answer this question, as you have said.  If the first items from the first set exists in the second then it will stop after finding that one value, it won't continue on to check the remaining elements.  The only issue is that the second parameter is loaded into a `HashSet` when the first value is checked.  This is comparable to iterating the entire set, which yours does on each iteration.  In short, if the very first item in the first set is a match this is a tad quicker, else this is slower.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Comparing one algorithm's performance at it's best case to another's worst case is not really fair. All solutions presented here work equally well with collections under 2K or so, but FWIW, `Intersect` is indeed the most performant beyond that.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Right, but no-one's going to write a GetHashCode that's that abysmal.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use

```
A.Any(x => B.Contains(x))
```

Comment: Well, yeah... but that's (worst case) `O(mn)`, while `Intersect` is `O(m+n)` (at all times)

Comment: never really thought about that

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a combination of `Intersect` and `Any`

```
bool match = A.Intersect(B).Any();
```